# PyQt : Qt Designer doesn't directly create the GridLayout. Why?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6

Why Qt Designer create a general widget and then create GridLayout object child object ?

```
self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
```

Can i directly create a child GridLayout object ?

```
self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
```

Comment: It must have been you that added the extra widget. Qt Designer always creates a default central-widget, and a grid-layout can easily be added directly to that (once some child widgets have been added first). So I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @floupinette If you want to set a main layout for a window, you must not add it from the widget box, but by right clicking on an empty area of that window. Read how to [use layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-layouts.html)